# Calling the set method of a property when changing elements within that property

Tags: c#

I have a class 'cropping' that contains 4 parameters:

```
public class Cropping
{
   public float Top { get; set; }
   public float Bottom { get; set; }
   public float Left { get; set; }
   public float Right { get; set; }
}
```

Within my UI class, I have an instance of the cropping class, that has a method call within the set block, to update the UI.

```
private Cropping croppingFactors;
/// <summary>Stores details on how to crop the image</summary>
public Cropping CroppingFactors
{
  get { return croppingFactors; }
  set 
  {
    croppingFactors = value;
    UpdateUIControls();
  }
}
```

The aim here is obviously to update the UI controls, everytime a change is made to one of the cropping factors, however, if I change an element within the Cropping class, i.e. a call to

```
CroppingFactors.Top = 5;
```

The set method of the CroppingFactors property is not being run.

How can I update the UI when I change an element within a class like this?

*edit*

I realise that the set property will not run because I have not set a new value to the cropping class. **My question is:** How do I invoke the 'UpdateUIControls()' method when I change any element within the Cropping class?

*edit 2*

**Thanks to the answer given by Aran Mulholland** - Here is my implementation for completeness:

I modified the Cropping class to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged class

```
public class Cropping : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private float top;
   public float Top
   {
     get { return top; }
     set
     {
       top = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged();
     }
   }       

   //Same for bottom, left and right

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
   {
     if(PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

And then in the UI class, I subscribed to the event:

```
public ImgHost()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  CroppingFactors.PropertyChanged += CroppingFactors_PropertyChanged;
}

private void CroppingFactors_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  UpdateUIControls();
}
```

So that's my implementation, just for completeness. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: How is what you have not working?

Comment: @roryap He's modifying the `Cropping` object returned by `CroppingFactors` - not setting the property.

Comment: "*The set method of the CroppingFactors property is not being run.*". Of course it is not being run -- the CroppingFactors property has not been assigned a different value, so why should the setter being executed? Note that you assign a different value to one of the properties of the Cropping object, but you do not assign a different value to the CroppingFactors property...

Comment: Question updated to clarify my goal - I know why it doesn't work at the moment (not setting the property) - I just don't know how to get it working. Thanks

Comment: You could raise an event in the Cropping class when a propterty changes (in the setter of the property). Then you can subscribe to the event in the class containing the Cropping field or property. Or check INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on the `Cropping` class. Subscribe to the property changed event from the UI class that is using the `Cropping` class as a property so that every time the property is set on any of the members of the `Cropping` class you can call the desired function.

Comment: This is correct but I had to read it twice, add a sample code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the `UpdateUIControls()` whenever anything changes, but it depends what needs to trigger the change.  Another alternative is add an event:

```
public event EventHandler PropertyUpdated;
```

And then whatever needs to update the control list, can call the method on the control in the event handler.